# Usar FtpWebRequest com uri https

Tags: c#, .net, http, ftp, webrequest

Srs(as), boa tarde,

Estou criando um serviço que irá efetuar upload de alguns arquivos para um link FTP, porem esse está como HTTPS (https://caminho/path).

ocorre que a classe FtpWebRequest não permite a utilização de uri hhtp/https, ocorrendo o erro abaixo.

Poderiam ajudar?

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' to type
>   'System.Net.FtpWebRequest'.

abaixo envio o trecho de código que estou utilizando.

```
            string uriPath = "https//caminho/path";
            FtpWebRequest request;
            FtpWebResponse response;
            try
            {
                request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriPath);//Aqui ocorre o erro!!!!
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userCred, passCred);
                request.UsePassive = true;

                DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(caminhoPath);

                foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
                {
                    FileInfo arquivo = new FileInfo(file.FullName);
                    byte[] fileContents = new byte[arquivo.Length];

                    using (FileStream fr = arquivo.OpenRead())
                    {
                        fr.Read(fileContents, 0, Convert.ToInt32(arquivo.Length));
                    }

                    using (Stream writer = request.GetRequestStream())
                    {
                        writer.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
                    }
                    response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                }
            }
            catch (WebException webEx)
```

Usando o address como "ftp://caminho.com:443/path"

Retorna o erro na chamada do GetRequestStream().

```
                using (Stream writer = request.GetRequestStream())//Erro aqui!!!
                {
                    writer.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
                }
                response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

> The requested URI is invalid for this FTP command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem certeza que o protocolo do link é FTP mesmo, e não HTTP(S)? Se um endereço é dado como `http://dominio.com/path`, então o servidor está "falando" HTTP. E como isso é uma verdade (praticamente) universal, todos os APIs assumem isso, razão pela qual a chamada a `WebRequest.Create("http://caminho/path")` vai retornar um `HttpWebRequest`. A solução realmente seria que o administrador do servidor lhe mande uma URL correta (inclusive o esquema).

Tendo dito o acima, se for realmente o caso de que o seu endereço vai para um servidor FTP, então você pode mudar o `scheme` do protocolo, o que vai fazer com que a chamada a `Create` retorne um objeto do tipo `FtpWebRequest`:

```
string uriPath = "https//caminho/path";
FtpWebRequest request;
try
{
    string ftpUriPath = uriPath.Replace("https://", "ftp://");
    request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpUriPath);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    // ...
}
catch (WebException webEx) { ... }
```

Note que talvez você tenha que especificar a porta (`ftp://caminho:443/path`) se o seu servidor HTTPS está falando FTP (443 é a porta *default* do protocolo HTTPS).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas nesse caso retorna erro no .GetRequestStream().
using (Stream writer = request.GetRequestStream())
                    {
                        writer.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
                    }
                    response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

The requested URI is invalid for this FTP command.

Comment: Uma coisa que você pode fazer é tentar usar o navegador para ir em `https://caminho`. Se você ver uma página, então o servidor não está falando FTP - ele está falando HTTP. E você não poderá usar um cliente FTP para falar com ele.

Comment: Carlos, o address que foi enviado necessita de usuário e senha para login, e após acesso é exibida uma página "igual" ao FTP.
Digo que  neste caso é FTP, pois acessei o link pelo APP SmartFTP e fiz Up/Down Loads de arquivos.

Comment: Dá uma olhada no Fiddler (ou no debugger do seu navegador, na seção de "network") pra saber que protocolo está sendo usado na página que é "igual ao FTP" - inclusive tente "baixar" um dos arquivos de lá. Se for FTP mesmo, então eu não sei o que está acontecendo (e eu apagarei a minha resposta)

Comment: HTTPS :-(...
outros detalhes.

   Request URL: https://pathcom.com/input/
   Request Method: GET
   Status Code: 200 / OK
 - Request Headers
   Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*
   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
   Accept-Language: en-US
   Authorization: ********
   Connection: Keep-Alive
   Host: pathcom.com
   Referer: https://pathcom.com/input/
   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
   Connection: Keep-Alive
   Content-Encoding: gzip
   Content-Length: 358
   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Comment: Essa requisição é HTTP, e não FTP... Se você conseguir usar uma ferramenta de network capture (tipo Fiddler) pode ver se o SmartFTP está usando HTTP ou FTP mesmo

Answer (score 1):

Srs(as), consegui resolver o problema...

Utilizando o componente `WebClient` e `UploadFile`.

Muito obrigado pela ajuda!!!!

segue código abaixo.

```
private void SendFiles(string fileName)
    {
        CredentialCache credCache;
        Uri uri;
        NetworkCredential netCredential;
        DirectoryInfo iDirectory;
        byte[] response;
        try
        {
            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {

                credCache = new CredentialCache();
                uri = new Uri(uriPath);
                netCredential = new NetworkCredential(userCred, passCred);

                credCache.Add(uri, AuthenticationSchemes.Basic.ToString(), netCredential);
                webClient.Credentials = credCache;
                response = webClient.UploadFile(string.Format("{0}{1}", uri, Path.GetFileName(fileName)), "PUT", fileName);
                System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response); 
            }

        }
        catch (WebException webEx)
        {
            throw webEx;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

Comment: Ótimo - usando HTTP (e não FTP) funcionou!